# Buggy CATransform3D?

Tags: ios, matrix, identity, matrix-multiplication, catransform3d

**EDITED**

(the example contained mistake so I replaced it with another one)

The following code is just an example how does it work:

```
CATransform3D temp = CATransform3DIdentity;
temp.m34 = -0.002;
temp = CATransform3DTranslate(temp, 0, -230, 0);
temp = CATransform3DRotate(temp, -M_PI / 5, 1, 0, 0);
temp = CATransform3DTranslate(temp, 0, 230, 0);
```

The output before the last line of code:

```
(lldb) po temp
 (m11 = 1, m12 = 0, m13 = 0, m14 = 0, m21 = 0, m22 = 0.809017002, m23 = -0.587785244, m24 = 0.00117557053, m31 = 0, m32 = 0.587785244, m33 = 0.809017002, m34 = -0.00161803409, m41 = 0, m42 = -230, m43 = 0, m44 = 1)
```

The output after the last line of code:

```
(lldb) po temp
 (m11 = 1, m12 = 0, m13 = 0, m14 = 0, m21 = 0, m22 = 0.809017002, m23 = -0.587785244, m24 = 0.00117557053, m31 = 0, m32 = 0.587785244, m33 = 0.809017002, m34 = -0.00161803409, m41 = 0, m42 = -43.9260902, m43 = -135.190613, m44 = 1.27038121)
```

Whats the ...? The last line of code does nothing because it is `E` (it is indentation matrix and multiplication with it should return the same result) but it have changed even the m44 element which must be always equal to 1.

And even if this matrix performs the same calculations as the correct one does then, for example, I can't simply take back a transform value which is stored in it.

Could anybody suggest a solution how to generate correct matrices (m44 == 1) except of multiplicating them manually?

Comment: A bit difficult to say here, would you mind showing your _real_ code?

Comment: What can't you understand particularly? `A` -> `A'` where `A'` reliably has `m44 == 1` using Objective-C features? The other text describes a concrete example and the unexpected result.

Comment: Edited: fixed a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a reason of the problem. Everything is correct because in `CATransform3D` all the transform matrices are transposed but I thought that they look like the following one:
[image]

So `m44 != 1` because m34 is not the `z` coordinate or another kind of translation. It means "perspective" which has influence on `m44` value. It also tangled me that `m44 == 1` until the last line of code.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you're trying to do. You create a `CATransform3D` called temp, but on the third line of your code you are using a variable called `transform` which is not mentioned elsewhere in your 3 lines of code. Maybe you meant to use `temp` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should be `temp` instead of `transform` and this example even should work so I need to post another example. Anyways I have some cases when `m44 != 1`

Comment: I have updated the question. Yes it works with multiplications on identity matrix but there is still something wrong with multiplications in general.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov there is nothing buggy with multiplications in general or with transforms.  You are using CATransform3DRotate before the translation so you are getting a result exactly as expected. If you perform the rotate last you'll see that m44 value of 1 is preserved.

Comment: I have answered with answer I hoped to hear from someone else. Yes, nothing buggy. No, I can't change the order of the translation and you should know - it is from the matrix theory that swapping of multiplying matrices changes the final result